# Deployment items not working with new Visual Studio 2010 test project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I created a new Visual Studio 2010 Test Project.

```
<solution>
    <test-project>
        Resources
            test-data.csv
        tests.cs
```

I added one test with one deployment item attribute.

```
[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("test-project\Resources")]
public void Some_unit_test() { ... }
```

The file in the `Resources` folder is not moving to the test results `out` directory and is not being found by the test code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *must* check "Enable deployment" in the Deployment section of the Test Settings for that project.